# Cox regression with no event in one treatment group

Tags: r, survival

I'm trying to calculate HR with IPTW for the effect of a drug, but no event occurs in one treatment group.
Here is a reprex (the only difference is that no weights are included here for simplicity)

```
set.seed(1)
summary(time <- runif(100, 0, 100))
table(drug <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50)))
table(event <- c(sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.75, .25)), rep(0, 50)), useNA = "ifany")
data <- data.frame(time, event, drug)
summary(coxph(Surv(time, event)~drug, data=data))
```

and this is the output:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ drug, data = data)

  n= 100, number of events= 8 

           coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
drug -2.107e+01  7.064e-10  1.453e+04 -0.001    0.999

     exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
drug 7.064e-10  1.416e+09         0       Inf

Concordance= 0.75  (se = 0.032 )
Likelihood ratio test= 9.56  on 1 df,   p=0.002
Wald test            = 0  on 1 df,   p=1
Score (logrank) test = 6.58  on 1 df,   p=0.01

Warning message:
In coxph.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Loglik converged before variable  1 ; coefficient may be infinite.
```

I know this problem has been already explained in other threads (for instance [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124821/dealing-with-no-events-in-one-treatment-group-survival-analysis) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572498/survival-analysis-no-failures-in-one-group/572528#572528)). However, it's still not clear how i can handle this to get meaningful coefficient (and HR).
This issue is also discussed by Therneau and Grambsch in Section 3.5, "Infinite Coefficients," of Modeling Survival Data--Extending the Cox Model, but i do not have this book (unfortunately).

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxphf/coxphf.pdf this also might be a good resource for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point in this scenario is that the maximum likelihood estimate for your coefficient *is* infinite, and the only differences between implementations is where they stop iterating. Further summarizing the reference you cited:

> The Wald test is worthless in this situation. [..] The score and likelihood ratio tests are still valid, however.

> We do not view this as a serious concern at all , other than an annoying
> numerical breakdown of the Wald approximation. One is merely forced
> to do the multiple fits necessary for a likelihood ratio or score test.

Finally, if you don't require adjustment for covariates as your example indicates & as explained in your links, you could always use a log-rank test (`survival::survdiff`) which is just a special case of the Cox model:

> Interestingly, similar concerns are rarely voiced about the use of the log-rank statistic in situations where one subset has no events.

**Addendum**

The confidence interval may be more meaningful than the point estimate (which is infinite) in this case, at least in that way you can get some kind of lower/upper bound on your parameter. As with previous inference you can't rely on Wald statistics for this. Profiling the likelihood isn't difficult, but I didn't immediately find a pre-packaged solution.

Below is an implementation for the 95% confidence limit of your parameter, loosely based on `survMisc::profLik` (which doesn't seem to work as-is for this scenario):

```r
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ drug, data = data)

## 95% critical value for the log-likelihood
crit_ll <- fit$loglik[2] - qchisq(.95, 1)/2

## Search for the parameter value where ll = crit
## NOTE: this only works here because the log-likelihood ISN'T a parabola!
##   (there would be 2 roots usually)
llfun <- function(x, fit, crit = 0) {
  update(fit, as.formula(paste0(".~+offset(", x, "*drug)")))$loglik - crit
}

uniroot(llfun, c(-40, 40), fit = fit, crit = crit_ll)
#> $root
#> [1] -1.116118
```

The upper 95% confidence limit for your HR is ~0.328 (or lower limit ~3.05 if you swap the reference for comparison).

Here's the profile likelihood solution graphically:
[image: profile log likelihood]

Note the asymptote to the left because the MLE is (negative) infinity, usually you'd have another downslope there with a 95% *lower* limit for the parameter and the MLE itself the value where the likelihood is maximized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that is definitely impossibile to get an HR in this specific case? Actually, my analysis should be IPT weighted (not reported in the example for simplicity)… and survdiff would give a p value for the different survival across the treatment groups but not HR.

Comment: You are trying to divide by zero. Of course it is "impossible", actually "undefined" would be the mathematical terminology.

Comment: @Devanto the HR estimate is trivially infinite or zero as well. Not very informative, but all you can get from such data. It might be more relevant to look at a (non-Wald!) confidence interval, that way you can still get a lower/upper bound on its value. That'll be one bound only; the other will still be infinite/zero. To me it seems your only other options are to include some kind of shrinkage/prior information -- which will then heavily determine the estimate you get -- or get more data.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I also got an answer by e-mail by Prof Therneau:

> The stack overflow answer copied my book, so is a good summary of my opinion.   The ratio of death rates is 0/something = 0, which is a perfectly valid result.   I don't get worried about it, any more than the OR of 0 that occurs when a 2x2 table has a 0 entry.
> If you want a confidence interval you have to use the profile likelihood.   It's the most accurate, but other than edge cases like this the usual beta +/- 2se gives the same answer to several digits.   So I've never bothered to create a function, though I have been asked to.  I just do it by hand.
> There is a small section "profile likelihood" in the main survival vignette.